# Generate titles from variables in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to generate titles automatically in Gnuplot. I have an array (titleprefix) and another set of variables (a1,a2,a3...), and the title is the prefix followed by the slope (the a's). I tried this:

```
title(n) = sprintf("word(titleprefix,n).sprintf(\" Slope = %.3f\",%f)",a."n"+0)
```

Of course that did not work. Error is:

> Non-numeric string found where a numeric expression was expected.

Any idea how I solve this?

Eventually, I would like to plot several curves like this:

```
plot f1 w l t title(1), \
     f2 w l t title(2), \
     f3 w l t title(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to do such things is to build the complete `set title` command inside such a function and then `eval` that.

In your case it requires a bit of brain twisting to get the quotes correct, so that the variable names are correct:

```
titleprefix="first second third"
a1 = 1.111
a2 = 2.222
a3 = 3.333
title(n) = 'set title "'.word(titleprefix, n).': ".sprintf("Slope = %.3f", a'.n.')'

set multiplot layout 1,3
eval(title(1))
plot x
eval(title(2))
plot 2*x
eval(title(3))
plot 3*x
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can construct a word list of the formatted variable values when you define or calculate the variables.

```
a1 = 1.111111
a2 = 2.222222
a3 = 3.333333
tmp = 'a = ""'
do for [i=1:3] { tmp = tmp.".sprintf('%.3f ', a".i.")" }
eval(tmp)

plot for [i=1:3] i*x title word(a, i)
```

[image]

Comment: That helps a lot, but I am not using multiplot. How would you do it if you want to plot several curves. `plot file1 w l t title(1),file2 w l t title(2)`

Comment: A classical case where a minimal, but full example script would have been helpful ;) So, to get the rest of the information: where do you get the variable values from?

Comment: It was hard to type a script in the comment. The question was how would you modify it if you did no use multiplot. For example, how would you evaluate the title commands if you wanted to do something like `plot file1 w l t title(1),file2 w l t title(2), file2 w l t title(3)`. The rest is the same as your working example.

Comment: You can always edit your question to include more information. Basically you could follow my advice at the end of the answer: You can generate a word list with preformatted variable values. I'll update my answer in a minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will work on it and see if I can get it working. By the way, I do have an error with trying your example. Version 4.6 patchlevel 4. `gnuplot> do for [i=1:3] { tmp = tmp."sprintf('%f ', a".i.")" }
gnuplot> eval(tmp)

gnuplot> a = sprintf('%f ', a1)sprintf('%f ', a2)sprintf('%f ', a3)sprintf('%f ', a1)sprintf('%f ', a2)sprintf('%f ', a3)sprintf('%f ', a1)sprintf('%f ', a2)sprintf('%f ', a3)
                               ^
         ';' expected`

Comment: Ups, didn't include the fixed version. Should work now.